# What real-time mechanism of PR2 use?

Tags: ros, real-time, orocos, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is PR2 using Orocos or linux-rt?

Is PR2 using soft real-time or hard real-time?

Is Orocos an soft real-time modules?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10432/what-real-time-mechanism-of-pr2-use?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.) it has one rt process (look [HERE](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism)), an Orocos controller for the PR2 is on our TODO list.

2.) see link above

3.) it is as real-time as your kernel allows it, if you have a real-time kernel it is hard real-time if you use pre-empt kernel or xenomai.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-09-30**:
A general linux scheduler can't provide you any guaranties, however sometimes it does satisfy for mobile robotic manipulators. ROS also is not optimal for real-time.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-09-28**:
So if I want to use rt process,should I install ROS on linux-rt kernel?